# Problema con Tabla en XSLT

Tags: html, xml, html-tabla, xslt

!Buenas!

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio que dice así:

> Mostrar una tabla con los pacientes que trata cada médico, usando colores distintos para médico y paciente.

He conseguido dejarlo de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el codigo en XSL:

```
    <h2>TABLA MEDICO-PACIENTE</h2>

<table border="2">

    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="medico">


            <th><font color="red"><xsl:value-of select="nombre"/></font></th>


        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="paciente/nombre"/></td>
        <td>Hola2</td>
        <td>Hola3</td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

**No he pegado todo el código ya que solo  me da problemas esta parte. No consigo hacer que me muestre los pacientes de cada medico. Ya he cambiado varias cosas pero no los coloca.**

Este es el XML:

```
    <ambulatorio>
  <paciente medico="1">
    <nss>1</nss>
    <nombre>Antonio Gómez</nombre>
    <fechanacimiento>10-10-1958</fechanacimiento>
  </paciente>
 <paciente medico="3">
    <nss>2</nss>
    <nombre>Carmen Ramírez</nombre>
    <fechanacimiento>12-1-1946</fechanacimiento>
  </paciente>
   <paciente medico="2">
    <nss>3</nss>
    <nombre>Felipe Pérez</nombre>
    <fechanacimiento>2-3-1980</fechanacimiento>
  </paciente>
   <paciente medico="1">
    <nss>4</nss>
    <nombre>Raul Romero</nombre>
    <fechanacimiento>12-5-2000</fechanacimiento>
  </paciente>
   <paciente medico="2">
    <nss>5</nss>
    <nombre>Laura Montes</nombre>
    <fechanacimiento>6-7-1987</fechanacimiento>
  </paciente>
  <medico>
    <id>1</id>
    <nombre>Álvaro Mesa</nombre>
  </medico>
    <medico>
    <id>2</id>
    <nombre>Alicia López</nombre>
  </medico>
    <medico>
    <id>3</id>
    <nombre>Enrique Pincel</nombre>
  </medico>
</ambulatorio>
```

**¿Como tengo que poner la tabla para que me ponga bien los pacientes?**

Comment: Básicamente los médicos los tengo en rojo, y quiero que abajo me aparezcan los pacientes a los que trata. Pero ya me he liado un poco la verdad